# How to improve performance on backend when data is fetched from multiple APIs in sequencial manner?

Tags: node.js, database, api

I am creating a Nodejs app that consumes APIs of multiple servers in a sequential manner as the next request depends on results from previous requests.
For instance, user registration is done at our platform in PostgreSQL database. User feeds, chats, posts are stored at getStream servers. User roles and permissions are managed through CMS. If in a page we want to display a list of user followers with some buttons as per the user permissions then first I need to find list of my current user's followers from getStream then enrich them with my PostgreSQL DB then fetch their permissions from CMS. Since one request has to wait for another it takes long time to give response.
I need to serve all that data in a certain format. I have used Promise.all() where requests were not depending on each other.
I thought of a way to store pre-processed data that is ready to be served but I am not sure how to do that. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi sumitk, as you have stated "the next request depends on results from previous requests" it's unlikely you can do much. Otherwise you will need to provide specific details of the data you are processing and how the dependencies of each request for anyone to provide input. Can you edit that information into your question?

Comment: Hi Matt, I had updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

*sequential manner as the next request depends on results from previous requests*

you could try using async/await so that each request will run in a sequential manner.

Comment: I am already using it but the problem is when this chain goes long the waiting time increases, sometimes even 5 - 10 sec, which gives a bad user experience.